# How to simplify filling a Form that has same content all the time?

Tags: java, html, forms

I have a software form that has my company name, address fields. I need to fill the same details every time. How to simplify it by pasting in one field will populate the remaining? I tried putting a tab(`\t`) but all text comes in one field only.

Comment: How does this relate to Java?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Modify an existing program to include an 'autofill'-like feature? or run something that'll type into multiple fields for you?

Comment: A form with the same content every time is called a "static web page" (ha ha). All kidding aside, though... Are you talking about the sort of thing where you would enter, say, your name, and then all your other details like street address, city, state, ZIP code, phone number, etc., get "magically" filled in?

Comment: I look at this and feel like what you're really looking for is a recommendation for something like [texter](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/texter_portable).

Comment: Hey Kevin, That's right! Actually, I have seen this somewhere. Maybe that software might build like that. I'm having a software that built by the shipping company. But they don't have that feature & I can't modify the code too. If it is available it will save a lot of time.